# Elan Pointing Device list does not show touchpad on Lenovo y510p

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

In an attempt to get a newer version of the Elan touchpad drivers, I have disrupted Elan's ability to see the touchpad device in the list of devices:

Here you can see nothing is showing :

[image]

But the device shows up here and in the Device Manager as well:

[image]

How can I get it back on the device list? I thought about editing the registry under Elantech/DeviceInformation because that looks like where it stores the hex addresses, but the odds of that being successful are very slim.

I tried installing other versions but none seem to fix the issue.

I tried uninstalling the hardware for the touchpad, then reinstalling the drivers for Elan, and it persisted.

I tried installing the drivers with windows 8 compatibility and Run As Administrator.

I tried doing an update drivers/rollback drivers to the 11.4.26.1 version and it continues to have this problem. When the ELAN drivers are not installed, there is a generic microsoft controller that it defaults to.

Edit: Tried uninstalling drivers for both the pointing device and the Elan SMBus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! In this solution, I reinstall the original drivers then install a newer version of the Elan touchpad drivers from acer. I set the touchpad device as an `ELAN PS/2 Port Input Device` instead of a `Lenovo pointing device`.

Steps:

1. Right click Uninstall `Lenovo point device` under Device Manager --> Mice and other pointing devices)
2. Right click Uninstall `Elan SMBus Driver` under Device Manager --> System Devices
3. Restart
4. Run the installer from Lenovo's [download list](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS035829) for the y510p.
5. Restart
6. Download/Extract anywhere Acer Notebook Aspire V3-771 drivers [TouchPad_ELANTECH_11.6.28.201_W81x64_A.zip](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/TouchPad/TouchPad_ELANTECH_11.6.28.201_W81x64_A.zip?acerid=635170560607154373&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20V3-771&OS=81P1&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6)
7. Open Device Manager and go to the `Lenovo pointing device` under Mice and other pointing devices
8. Select the `Driver` tab and select `Update Driver...`
9. Select the second option, `Browse my computer for driver software
10. Select the green arrow option, `Let me pick form a list of device drivers on my computer`
11. Select the button `Have disk...`
12. Navigate to the folder where the acer drivers are extracted
13. Select the `ETD.inf` file in the corresponding folder to your OS - 32 or 64bit.
14. Select `ELAN PS/2 Port Input Device`
15. Accept the disclaimer to install the drivers and restart after installation
16. Success!

It looks like the ETDCtrl that shows the properties has a fewer options than Lenovo's version. At this point I could try reinstalling the Lenovo drivers again.

Ironically, this solution of installing another providers drivers is what caused the original problem.

Comment: Something obnoxious that has occurred with this version is that I no longer have the ability to enable/disable the touchpad on demand. FN+F6 does not work. I can only disable the touchpad by selecting the "Disable when other pointing devices are plugged in" option.